# Loading an image from raw data with Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am quite suprised since I'm not able to find any method that loads an image from raw data. Is there any elegant way to do it? I just need to create a QImage or similar from raw bitmap binary data (no header).

Comment: If "raw data" means output of a library so, an important note is that some cases needs to apply `stride` value. e.g. transform mupdf library output to QImage. Also look at byte order and used render format standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a QImage object from raw data with the ctor that takes an array of uchars.
You need to specify the format of the data given to the QImage (RGB, RGBA, Indexed, etc.)

```
QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, 
         Format format )
```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qimage.html

E.g.:

```
uchar* data = getDataFromSomewhere();
QImage img(data, width, height, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dear Lucas, thanks for your answer. Of course it helps! The problem is that I do not want to create a new instance of a QImage object. Thanks anyway. Cheers

Comment: @DídacPérez Creating a new image instance and assigning this to an existing object shouldn't really do any harm considering the copy-on-write semantics of Qt's heavy-weight value types.

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear. use Qpixmap. and Qbyte array. its very easy.

```
  QPixmap pic;
  pic.loadFromData(array); //array contains a bite array of the image.
  label->setPixmap(pic);  //do what ever you want from the image. here I set it to a lable.
```

Comment: Dear Lakshan, you have answered exactly the same as digitalSurgeon, please read my comments above.